# Div positioning (learning css)

Tags: html, css

I am learning basic css, I've got a basic understanding of html. I was watching a YT video on css and cannot get my code to replicate what is shown on the screen. I've tried for an hour now. I'm sure it's something super simple, but you don't know what you don't know kind of thing.

I'm trying to get 2 colored blocks to stack one then the other. but they're just stacking on top of each other. I typed out my code just like it showed on the video. @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0Z1oNQ93Wo&list=PLLAZ4kZ9dFpNO7ScZFr-WTmtcBY3AN1M7&index=7

my code is:

```html
<html>
        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>CSS learning</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>CSS Tutorial</h1>

          <div style="width:90px; height:90px; background-color:blue;">
          <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;">


        </body>
    </html>
```

the red block is covering up the blue one, and not stacking on one another like in the video.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have the option try to use the code snippet instead of code block. I did that for you this time. You can see it is better

Comment: You are missing the closing `div` tags.

Comment: @Spectric can't blame. I jumped through the video and the screen never shows them.

Comment: Divs are block level elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements. You should look into either changing them into another type or wrapping the parent and changing it.
You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed the div into the div. They are on the same hierarchy.

```
<div>
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ha man don't feel bad. This is how we learn. And trust me, there are quite a few experienced people who still face difficulty in centering a div lol

Comment: Agreed with @AB7zz - trust me I'd probably stackoverflow that. We were all there before

Answer (score 0):

If you want one div on top of the other do it like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>CSS learning</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>CSS Tutorial</h1>

      <div style="width:90px; height:90px; background-color:blue;">
      </div>
      <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;">
      </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the css position. Here in short: If you set `position: absolute` of any element, it will position absolutely according to the nearest parent which has the position property of relative. So, if you want to stack one div to another - you need to give their parent position of relative, And give them/one of them position of absolute.

```html
<div>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: red; height: 150px; width: 150px"></div>
  <div style="background-color: green; height: 150px; width: 150px"></div>
</div>
```

In this case the parent div has the position of relative by default.